# Text Input Property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a form using React and Material UI. I'm supposed to add a helper, when the user is starts typing in the Text input field. What is property which I could use ? The helper should not be displayed when moved to next text input field

Comment: Could you provide some codes what you tried so far?

Comment: I'm still not sure how to solve this

Comment: You might wanna take a look at tooltips: https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you need the events to show and hide helper for each input?

Comment: What exactly is a "helper" for a text input? Like clippy from Microsoft Word? Or do you mean an "input mask" that formats text to a specific pattern as you type for currencies/dates/etc?

Comment: Yes show and hide "helper text", Suppose Input text field for Name, helper text would be "Only Letter, No digits or text to entered". Show this helper text when used is typing and hide it when he moves to next input field

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to achieve is "show" and "hide" `<div>Some helper Text</div>` based on the text input `< TextField />` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have that on a [Textfield](https://material-ui.com/es/api/text-field/) there is a `helperText` prop that you can use to show some information useful information to the user. Take a look at the docs and give it a shot.

You can use the input value to know if the user has typed something and show this helperText conditionally, I'm not sure if I understood what you wanted but I'm guessing it goes this way.

I've added here a sample of a helperText showing only when the user is typing https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-supmg?fontsize=14

Comment: This TextField would display `helperText` always. I want this helperText to be showed only when user is typing. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is "show" and "hide" based on the text input event.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to achieve is "show" and "hide" `<div>Some helper Text</div>` based on the text input `< TextField />` event.